# Reverse Integer in Endless Loops

Tags: c, integer, reverse, digits

Hey its OK to when i set value for integer but i dont want just reverse one i want reverse integer in a endless loop(infinite) so here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
int num = 2, preNum, digit;


while (1)
{
    while (num > 0)
    {
        preNum = num;
        digit = preNum % 10;
        printf("%d", digit);
        preNum /= 10;
    }
    num++;
}




getch();
return 0;
}
```

here is the wrong par ?

Comment: Your loop condition, `num > 0`, will cause the loop to execute until `num` overflows, which is undefined behavior.

Comment: `preNum /= 10;` is pointless because you have `preNum = num;` at the beginning of the loop.

Comment: ok thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to change your code to something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num = 2, preNum, digit;

    while (num < 100)
    {
        preNum = num;
        printf("%d: ", preNum);
        while(preNum)
        {
            digit = preNum % 10;
            printf("%d", digit);
            preNum /= 10;
        }
        printf("\n");

        num++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The following output is produced:

```
$ gcc main.c -o main.exe; ./main.exe
2: 2
3: 3
4: 4
5: 5
6: 6
7: 7
8: 8
9: 9
10: 01
11: 11
12: 21
13: 31
14: 41
15: 51
16: 61
17: 71
18: 81
19: 91
20: 02
...
```

Comment: You are awesome bro THANK YOU

Comment: @CodeJunky Please check the accept button if this answers your question.